# spring mvc, mark a single row in jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

My controller returns me a list of objects, which i render on a jsp. Whats i want to do is select a single row and mark it to be deleted.

But im not sure how to go about this:

I started with this:

```
  form
    table
        c:forEach var="book" items="${booklist}" 
            tr
                td>{book.id}</td
                td>{book.Number}</td
                td>{book.Address}</td
                td><input type="submit" name="delete" value="{book.id}" ..</td
            tr
        c:forEach>
    table>
```

(...apologies for formatting...)

I have two problems with the above, firstly it displays the id on the button. and secondly i still would ideally like to bind the selected row to a form so i can do some validation

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wrap each row in it's own form, with a hidden input holding the id of the book to delete:

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${book.id}"/>
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Delete"/></td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

Don't forget your $s.

Answer (score 0):

I would get rid of having a button all together, and use an anchor tag (you can style anchor's to look like buttons with css anyway, and they place nicely with :hover pseudoelements, etc.)

Ideally, your backing controller would handle a delete action with a given ID.  If you're using Spring-MVC usually you can have a RESTful URL so something like the following might work:

```
<a href="/book/delete/${book.id}">Delete</a>
```

The only thing you have to be concerned with, and it's a valid concern, is making sure not everyone can just willy nilly delete your stuff.  With this approach, or the approach you are trying to use, anyone can execute the HTTP request if they know the id of what they want to delete.  Make sure a destructive action like this is protected with something like security credentials, validating a user, etc.